# Singular Value Decomposition of this matrix with a zero singular value

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition

What is the singular value decomposition of $$
   \left[ \begin{matrix}
    2 & -6\\
    1 & -3 \\
    0 & 0 \\
    \end{matrix}\right]
$$

Singular value decomposition calculators online give the following answer: 
$$
    \left[\begin{matrix}
    2 & -6\\
    1 & -3 \\
    0 & 0 \\
    \end{matrix}\right]
=
   \left[\begin{matrix}
    -2/\sqrt{5} & -1/\sqrt{5} & 0 \\
    -1/\sqrt{5} & 2/\sqrt{5} & 0\\
    0 & 0 & 1\\
    \end{matrix}\right]
  \left[ \begin{matrix}
    \sqrt{50} & 0\\
     0& 0 \\
    0 & 0 \\
    \end{matrix}\right]
  \left[ \begin{matrix}
    -.3162 & .9487\\
    .9487 & -.3162 \\
    \end{matrix}\right]
$$
I get the same singular values: $\sqrt{50}$ and $0$. However, this is as far as I get. I get the normalized eigenvalues as $\left[\begin{matrix} 2/\sqrt{5}\\1/\sqrt{5} \end{matrix}\right]$ and $\left[\begin{matrix} 1/\sqrt{5}\\-1/\sqrt{5} \end{matrix}\right]$, instead of $\left[\begin{matrix} -.3162\\ .9487 \end{matrix}\right]$ and $\left[\begin{matrix} .9487\\-.3162 \end{matrix}\right]$. What am I doing wrong? I have checked my work multiple times.

Comment: As an additional comment, the singular values are unique to within a given order (that is why convention puts them in decreasing order).  However, even if the singular values are ordered by convention, the singular vectors are not guaranteed to be unique.  For example, you can always multiply both the left and right singular vectors associated with a particular singular vector by -1 and still have a perfectly valid SVD.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to get the SVD of the matrix you need to get the eigenvalues of the covariance matrix

$$  A =\begin{bmatrix} 2& -6\\ 1 & -3  \\ 0 & 0   \end{bmatrix} \tag{1}$$

$$ A^{T}A = \begin{bmatrix} 5& -15\\ -15& 45  \end{bmatrix}\tag{2}$$

$$ \det(A^{T}A - \lambda I) = \begin{vmatrix} 5- \lambda& -15\\ -15& 45-\lambda  \end{vmatrix} = (5-\lambda)(45-\lambda) -225 \tag{3}$$
$$ \det(A^{T}A - \lambda I) = \lambda(\lambda-50) \implies \lambda_{1} = 50 \lambda_{2} = 0 \tag{4}$$

now $A^{T}A = V \Lambda V^{T} $

we find the right singular vectors

$$  A^{T}A -50I = \begin{bmatrix} 5-50& -15\\ -15& 45 -50 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}x_{1} \\ x_{2} \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 0  \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} \tag{5}$$

$$  A^{T}A-50I = \begin{bmatrix} -45 &-15\\ -15& -5 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}x_{1} \\ x_{2} \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 0  \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} \tag{6}$$

$$ -45x_{1} -15x_{2} = 0 \\ -15x_{1} - 5x_{2} = 0  $$ 
then $x_{2} = \frac{x_{1}}{3}$

$$ x = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 3\end{bmatrix} \tag{7} $$

now normalize

$$ v_{1} = \begin{bmatrix} \frac{1}{\sqrt{3^{2}+1}}\\ \frac{3}{\sqrt{3^{2}+1}} \end{bmatrix} \tag{8} $$
$$ v_{1} = \begin{bmatrix} \frac{1}{\sqrt{10}}\\ \frac{3}{\sqrt{10}} \end{bmatrix} \tag{9} $$

for the next

$$  A^{T}A = \begin{bmatrix} 5& -15\\ -15& 45 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}x_{1} \\ x_{2} \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 0  \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} \tag{10}$$

you get the opposite

$$ v_{2} = \begin{bmatrix} \frac{-3}{\sqrt{10}}\\ \frac{1}{\sqrt{10}} \end{bmatrix} \tag{11} $$

the singular values are the square roots of the eigenvalues so..you have $\sigma_{1} = \sqrt{50} , \sigma_{2} =0$

if you do it by python ..

import numpy as np

```
A = np.matrix([[2,-6],[1,-3],[0,0]])
u,s,vt = np.linalg.svd(A)
```

these aren't unique.. you should note..

```
matrix([[-0.31622777,  0.9486833 ],
        [ 0.9486833 ,  0.31622777]])
```

if you do the $AA^{T}$

$$AA^{T} = \begin{bmatrix} 40& 20 & 0 \\ 20 & 10 &  0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \tag{12}$$

then take

$$ \det(AA^{T} - \lambda I) = \begin{vmatrix} 40-\lambda& 20 & 0 \\ 20 & 10-\lambda  &  0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{vmatrix}  \tag{13}$$

in the end if $U \Sigma V^{T} = A $ you'll be fine..